# Nokogiri : find all the anchors that match a name

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to save the links only of the sample pages in this website
[MusicRadar](https://www.musicradar.com/news/tech/free-music-samples-royalty-free-loops-hits-and-multis-to-download)

```rb
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
link = 'https://www.musicradar.com/news/tech/free-music-samples-royalty-free-loops-hits-and-multis-to-download'
html = OpenURI.open_uri(link)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
#used grep because every sample link in that page ends with '-samples'
doc.xpath('//div/a/@href').grep(/-samples/)
```

The problem is that it only finds 3 of that links
What am I doing wrong?
And If i wanted to open each of that links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS selectors are more useful than XPath (if the document structure is good enough for that)

Now you used XPath with similar to CSS selector `div > a`, but you don't need it because for example some of the links inside `p`

If you need all links with `-samples` you can use [`*=` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attrvalue_6)

```rb
doc.css('a[href*="-samples"]') # return Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet with matched elements

doc.css('a[href*="-samples"]').map { |a| a[:href] } # return array of URLS
```

Comment: thank you,can you explain the parameter of the css method? Or point to some wiki

Comment: Just select all `a` tags with `href` attribute contains `-samples`. You can read more about such selectors by the link provided in the answer